# One relation for two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I was trying to find answer on my question, but didn't success with it.

I have models Event, participants, participation_form, invitation, user.

```
Event has_many participants
User has_many invitations
User has_many participation_form
```

For Participant I want to have field like "based_on" and it will be references with invitation or participation_form.

I have one idea about it - make two fields and one model method that will be check which field contains value and return "based_on"

My question is - is there any way to reference one model to two models with pair of fields - class (model name) and value (id) so I will add another type if I need it in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use polymorphic associations for that: (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Could you tell more about models relations so I can write some example? Why do you need Participant model?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It will be like social network event, where organizers can invite users to event and user can send participation request, I want to show to organizers how user joined event (with invite or participation form).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by`Kuba Ploskonka`, you'll probably benefit from a [`polymorphic association`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) here:

[image]

--

**Setup**

> For Participant I want to have field like "based_on" and it will be references with invitation or participation_form.

As per your specifications, you'll want to use the following:

```
#app/models/participation.rb
Class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :participle, polymorphic: true
end

#app/models/invitation.rb
Class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :participations, as: :participle
end

#app/models/participation_form.rb
Class ParticipationForm < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :participations, as: :participle
end
```

This will give you the ability to save your objects as follows:

```
#app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb
Class InvitationsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @invitation = Invitation.new invitation_params
      @invitation.participations.build #-> will save a blank "Participation" object 
      @inviation.save
   end
end
```